# Broken brew-installed postgresql on lion

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I know there are a lot of lion-postgresql related questions on stack overflow already, but none seem to solve my problem.

I installed the homebrew of postgresql and everything was fine after that. Then I messed around a bit with the the libpq.dylib link in /usr/lib so that an application would link to the brew installed version rather than the OS-installed version. Somehow I managed to break my install while doing this in such a way that any call to psql gives the following error:

```
>psql
psql: invalid connection option "client_encoding"
```

reinstalling postgresql with 'brew remove postgresql' and another 'brew install postgresql' doesn't seem to help (same error). I've also relinked /usr/lib/libpq.dylib to be /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib, which is what I believe it was before.

Also, a potentially related problem is that my postgres server doesn't seem to want to shut down:

```
>pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres stop -s -m fast     
pg_ctl: server does not shut down
```

Anyone have any clues as to what is wrong? Alternatively, how would I completely uninstall and reinstall the postgres server and client?

Comment: What do you mean by "messed around a bit with the the libpq.dylib link" did you point the symlink to a different version of libpq?

Comment: I have no clue what you did to break it, but maybe it would prove easier to remove it and install Postgres.app?  Ref:  http://postgresapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try `/usr/local/bin/psql`. If that doesn't work, take a look at `which psql`.

Lion comes with a installation of postgresql running, and you might be using the stock `psql` instead of the brew `psql`.

Or that one might be running, and using the brew psql to connect to the Lion postgres instance.

Verify that `/usr/local/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`. Check `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

Fix that worked for me:

- if you use pgAdmin:

  ```
  show server_encoding;
  ```

  -bash-4.1$ export PGCLIENTENCODING='UTF8'
     -bash-4.1$ psql

psql (9.3.3)
   Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
...

put var in .profile or .bashrc

Answer (score 1):

If you installed postgresql via homebrew:

```
brew update
brew doctor
```

> Unexpected dylibs:
>       /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
>
> Unexpected .la files:
>       /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.la

```
brew upgrade postgresql
```

> Error: The `brew link` step did not complete successfully

```
brew link --overwrite postgresql
```

Then you should be fine to run the `psql` command.

Answer (score 1):

if you've `brew doctor`'d and already have the latest version of postgres, run

`brew unlink postgresql && brew link postgresql`

then

`brew link --overwrite postgresql`